# Alert.alert not working in React native iOS, but perfectly fine in Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Please check the code ,

```
import { 
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';

 checkForSendingOtp = () => {
    let hash = 'aBcDeGgd';
    Platform.OS === 'android'
     ? RNOtpVerify.getHash()
        .then(text => {
          hash = text + ''.replace('[', '');
          hash = hash + ''.replace(']', '');
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.sendDataForOtp(hash);
        })
        .catch(console.log)
    : this.sendDataForOtp(hash);
  };

sendDataForOtp(hash) {

axios.post(url,{hash:hash}).then(response=>{
  Alert.alert(
    'Login Failed',
    'Multiple Logins Are Found. \n Logout From All Other Devices to Continue.',
    [
      {
        text: 'Proceed ?',
        onPress: () => {}                       
      },
      {
        text: 'No',
        onPress: () => {},
      },
    ],
    {cancelable: false},
   );
  });
}


render() {
   return (
    <Ripple
        style={{
           position: 'absolute',
           top: 0,
           bottom: 0,
           left: 0,
           right: 0,
              }}
        onPress={this.checkForSendingOtp}
    />
)}
```

This snippet will work fine in android but not showing in iOS. why ?

Nb :- this is the most of the code that I can share right now , Edited the code please check it now and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: If that's the code you are using, you forgot to close the bracket of the proceed button. But it's strange it works on Android

Comment: this not the code  that I am using. that just a typo while coping code from vs code to stack overflow. thank for your finding

Comment: Make "sendDataForOtp" function to fat arrow function

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't exactly know what happened,  There were also a model component which I used for showing custom loading, after removing the model component the alerts starts working.

Answer (score 1):

Replace alert code with below

```
Alert.alert(
        'Login Failed',
        'Multiple Logins Are Found. \n Logout From All Other Devices to Continue.',
        [
          {
            text: 'Proceed ?',
            onPress: () => {}
          },
          {
            text: 'No',
            onPress: () => {},
            style: 'cancel'
          }
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      );
```

Comment: thank for the replay. this time it shows the alert but closes immediately

Comment: I didn't get you, closes immediately means?

Comment: it automatically closes.

Comment: Works August 2021

Answer (score 1):

It's probably related to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10471

For some weird reasons, having the Alert called in a "setTimeout" function make it work. But it’s **clearly NOT the best way** to avoid this problem. You can also try this solution:  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10471#issuecomment-513641325

```
 setTimeout(() => {
    Alert.alert(
      "title",
      "content",
      [
        {
          text: "ok",
          onPress: () => {

          },
        },
      ],
    )
  }, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    setTimeout(() => {      
        //TODO  use return and setTimeout           
        return Alert.alert(
        i18n.t('notAtYard.alertTitle'),
        'Invalid username or password',
        [
            {
                text: 'Ok',
                onPress: () => {
                    setUserPassword('');
                    setUsername('');
                },
            }
        ],
        {cancelable: false},
    );

    }, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

So in my case, I was not using any custom `Modal` because for custom `Modal` the solution is simple to wait until the `Modal` is closed but, I was using the `react-native` `Spinner` component, and I was hiding it properly using the `visible={loading}` prop and yes, the issue was also not resolved after setting `cancelable: false`  in the `Alert.alert` config and when I increased the timeout to `5000` it worked even without defining `cancelable: false` in the `Alert.alert` config but this a lot of timeout was not good for UX so I quickly checked out the `Spinner` component props and I came to know that it does have `cancelable?: boolean | undefined` prop so now when I used `Spinner` component like below it worked even without timeout.

```
<Spinner
    visible={loading}
    cancelable={true}
/>
```

**TLDR:** use `cancelable={true}` prop with `Spinner` component.